# Pre-upload Image File Manipulation

Tags: javascript, image, upload

Is there any 'hack' that can be applied to do client-side image processing with Javascript and/or CSS/HTML but NO flash?  Specifically, is this possible?

(1) First, user selects local file via html file upload mechanism, then
(2) javascript accesses local file and runs an algorithm to decrease amount of data uploaded before the form submission is executed.

I think I could do an asynchronous AJAX upload to another server, manipulate the image, return the new URL as (and IMG) to a hidden iFrame, and grab this image before submitting the form.  Would this work, or is there a better approach?

The purpose is to radically decrease server load by eliminating the possibility that multi-megapixel images will be uploaded when all the Web app wants is a thumbnail version.

Tanks.

Comment: Wait a sec here - a solution that involves *another* server, with the purpose being to "radically decrease server load" ... something doesn't make sense.

Comment: The short answer is that there's no easy way to do this cross-browser without flash. Why not just limit the upload size to some reasonable upper limit (500kb, for example)?

Comment: To clarify, paragraph 3 is asking, in part, if you can switch the upload image with a URL image prior to file upload?  If yes, would changing the width and height affect the actual data uploaded?

Comment: Pointy: I want to absolutely decrease the processing of the upload on the primary server as it will be high volume, and I can scale up a network of 'image processing' servers.

Comment: Javascript FileUpload object is read only.  Also, it only stores the filename, not an image reference.  So you can't do a switch :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly you will need a plugin for this. Flash, Java applets or any other plugin. But be aware of security issues. Flash just allowed it in the last few versions.

You can upload the image to another server and process it there. And then you can download it from your current server, you don't need to manipulate the URL or use iframes. Store the processed image and return an ID so you can get it later.